Can't communicate with Redis container ASP.NET Core
I'm trying create a demo in ASP.NET Core 8 to save data in Redis cache. Everything works perfectly when I use localhost:6379. But when my app.net container is running and try to communicate with the container Redis, by using container name like http://redis:6379, I get an error:

UnableToConnect on http://redis:6379/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted

Here is my compose:
api:
    image: api:latest
    container_name: api
    build:
        context: ../src/api
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "5168:5168"
    environment:
        - aspnetcore_environment=Production
        - aspnetcore_urls=http://+:5168
        
        
redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/redis.data:/usr/share/root/redis
      - ./volumes/redis.conf:/usr/share/redis/redis.conf
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=Teste@123
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_DATABASES=16   
    command: [ "redis-server", "/usr/share/redis/redis.conf"]

And here my program.cs file:
var redisOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints = { { appServicesSettings.RedisHost, appServicesSettings.RedisPort } },
    AbortOnConnectFail = false,
    DefaultDatabase = 0,
    ConnectTimeout = 15000,
    SyncTimeout = 15000
};

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = appServicesSettings.Redis;
    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisOptions));

appsettings.json:
"AppServicesSettings": {
    "RedisLocal": "localhost:6379",
    "RedisHost": "http://redis",
    "RedisPort": 6379
}

Version used:
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="8.0.4"


Ok, i fixed by made a little change in my appsetting
change this
  "AppServicesSettings": {
    "RedisLocal": "localhost:6379",
    "RedisHost": "http://redis",
    "RedisPort": 6379
  }

to this:
  "AppServicesSettings": {
    "RedisLocal": "localhost:6379",
    "RedisHost": "redis",
    "RedisPort": 6379
  }

Remove "http://" from Redis host: In the appsettings.json file, remove the "http://" prefix from Redis host. Redis does not normally use the HTTP protocol for communication, only TCP. Therefore, the host should just be "redis", without the "http://".
